# nfs volume mount connection refuse error in docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, nfs, docker-volume

I've got trouble with mounting an NFS share as a volume for a container.
I received connection refuse error.

```
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/unzip_volume/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/File_Management:/var/lib/docker/volumes/unzip_volume/_data,
data: addr=192.168.0.10,nfsvers=4: connection refused
```

This is my docker-compose nfs volume

```
volumes:
  unzip_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=192.168.0.10,nfsvers=4
      device: :/File_Management
```

what should i change in the code, thanks in advance